# Laravel pagination {{$users->links}} doesnt exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have set a view composer whit view share that give User data to the sidebar when i try to paginnate it while using

```
User::paginate(1)
```

and put $users->links into the blade it says links is not found but when I use

```
User::all()
```

It works and give no erros back but i can not paginate the table i dont see where the error is coming from. this is the error display:

> Call to undefined method App\User::links() (View: 
>         C:\Users\kaasv\medialab\resources\views\layouts\sidebar.blade.php) 
>         (View: 
>         C:\Users\kaasv\medialab\resources\views\layouts\sidebar.blade.php) 
>         (View: 
>         C:\Users\kaasv\medialab\resources\views\layouts\sidebar.blade.php)

**AppServiceProvider**

```
   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   //use Illuminate\View\View;
   use View;
   //use App\Repositories\UserRepository;

   use App\User;

  class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    View::share('user', User::paginate(1));

}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    //
}
}
```

**the sidebar.blade.php**

```
    <h1>Alle Studenten</h1>

  @if (Auth::check())


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Student Number</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($user as $users)

        <tr>
            <th scope="row">
               {{$users->id}}
            </th>
            <th>
                <a class="text-dark" href="/admin/leerling/{{ $users->id }}">
                    {{$users->name}}
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                {{$users->student_number}}
            </th>
        </tr>

    @endforeach

</table>

{{ $users->links() }}

     @endif
```

Comment: No users, but user: `{{ $user->links() }}`

Comment: Your variable naming is one reason for the confusion.  Why would you name the paginated collection `user` but a single item `users`?

Comment: @Devon yeah should probably change that, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't suggest using `Laravel's View Composers` because they will be initialized on every view, even the ones you add with `@include`, `@extends`, etc. Which might lead to big performance hit if the data you are sharing from the Composers is pulled from the Database.

Second of all, `paginate()` method accepts `number of results to return` as it's parameter, which would mean by returning only `1` user will resolve to `Paginator` instance which in fact has method you are looking for: `links()`, but the issue is you're naming it `user` where you are accessing `users` inside the view